# How to return unsigned char array from C shared library to calling python function

Tags: python, c, shared-libraries, ctypes

My C Program is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

unsigned char* test()
{
    unsigned char* abc = "\x80\x31\x00\x00\x05";
    return abc;
}
```

And my Python code is:

```
from ctypes import *
sh_obj=cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfile.so')
sh_obj.test.restype=c_char_p

print sh_obj.test()
```

But I am not getting the desired output.
The current output is:

�1

How to get the correct output?I need the output in the same format as input.

Comment: What is the desired output? And what is that current output in hex? �1 does not contain much information about the binary.

Comment: The desired output is the string defined in C file.

Comment: Then in terms of ascii, the �1 IS the desired output. `\x80 = (unknown character)` and `\x31 = 1`, finally the `\x00` is a null terminator, so python ignores it. See it here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: I want the output to remain an unsigned char array like the C.

Comment: That's impossible with python. Python is agnostic to signed, unsigned, or size. When talking between shared objects and python, there is no guarantee the datatypes will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `restype` `POINTER(c_ubyte)`, as in the following:

```
from ctypes import *
sh_obj=cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfile.so')
sh_obj.test.restype=POINTER(c_ubyte)
ret=sh_obj.test()
retl=[ret[i] for i in range(5)]
print(retl)
```

If your C `test()` function returns a pointer to the string literal `"\x80\x31\x00\x00\x05"`, this will print the following:

```
[128, 49, 0, 0, 5]
```

which are the unsigned byte values in decimal.

Comment: It gives error when declaring as unsigned char abc[]. why?

Comment: @SarangS Because `unsigned char abc[]` would have _automatic_ storage duration (on the stack) that would no longer be valid after `test()` has returned. That would be _undefined behavior_ in C. On the other hand, the pointer `unsigned char *abc` is pointing to a string literal that has _static_ storage duration that is valid after `test()` has returned.

Comment: What if in the given example,I have a char array that takes input from user. Then how to use it?Then I have an array as unsigned char c[512];Should I use malloc

Comment: You can use `malloc()` but if the memory is allocated by your `test()` function, you will need to provide some way to free the memory to avoid memory leaks (by saving the pointer returned by `sh_obj.test()` and passing it to a different function to free the memory block when no longer required). You could wrap this all in a Python function to free the memory once it has been converted to a Python variable.